# How can I play the data frame get from streaming by Live555?

Tags: ios, ipad, h.264, live555

My iOS App is a player to streaming video from monitor camera. There are two streaming mode: HTTP and RTP/RTSP.

---

HTTP:

Media Container ： MPEG-2 TS

Video Codec     ： H.264 (MPEG-4 AVC)

Audio Codec     ： AAC

RTP/RTSP:

Media Container ： MPEG4

Video Codec     ： H.264 (MPEG-4 AVC)

Audio Codec     ： AAC

---

In HTTP mode, I can play successfully with MPMoviePlayerViewController.

In RTP/RTSP mode, I used Live555 to implement the protocol RTP/RTSP. We just got the data from streaming and stored to a temperature file such as DATA.MP4. We don't use ffmpeg to decode the data because the license.

I used MPMoviePlayerViewController to play DATA.MP4 file but it can't. As above information, HTTP and RTP/RTSP have the same video profile H.264, so **I wonder that why the MPMoviePlayerViewController can't play DATA.MP4?**

By the way, I'm trying to use OpenH264(Cisco) to decode the DATA.MP4, but I don't know how to use this library. Because it isn't more document about it. **Anyone who have experience about it, can you share me some samples?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can save a RTSP steam to an mp4 using openRTSP, which also provides a source code example of how it do it. http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/

I have managed to decode an RTSP stream using openh264 but there are a few things to be aware of. See http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/faq.html#testRTSPClient-how-to-decode-data for an overview.

- Derive a new class from MediaSink
- For an overview of the openh264 decoder API, see https://github.com/cisco/openh264/wiki/UsageExampleForDecoder
- Before you initialize the h264 decoder, you need to get some parameters from the subsession: string spropParams = subsession->fmtp_spropparametersets(); and pass that into your sink object.
- During decode, the sink's AfterGettingFrame method gets repeated called. Each time, a H264 "NAL frame" is passed in, which is either a H264 frame fragment or a group of H264 parameters.
- Each frame needs a start code 0x00000001 prepended to the buffer before it is sent to the decoder. See H264or5VideoFileSink.cpp (in the live555 source) for an example of how this is done. https://github.com/xanview/live555/blob/master/liveMedia/H264or5VideoFileSink.cpp
- The sprop parameters should be transmitted to the decoder before any other data is sent. See H264or5VideoFileSink.cpp for this too.
- Use the DecodeFrameNoDelay (for immediate display of multi-slice data) or DecodeFrame2 (for display of only complete frames) function in openh264 for decoding https://github.com/cisco/openh264/wiki/ISVCDecoder#decodeframenodelay
- A frame is only ready when sDstBufInfo.iBufferStatus is true
- The frame is often encoded in some non-RGB colour space such as I420. One way to deal with this is opencv's cvtColor and the COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420 option.
- I had some difficulty with frames failing to decode when RTSP was working over UDP (I was getting dsRefLost errors). This may be due to some frames being larger than the MTU for the network, resulting in packet loss. A work around is to use TCP for RTSP instead or simply increase the network MTU. https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-November/000901.html

I hope that helps!